# Mocking both Model.objects.bulk_create and Model.save()

Tags: python, django-models, mocking

I'm attempting to mock *both* `bulk_create` and `save` for a dry run. 
I've created code which in essence does following:

```py
@mock.patch.object(SomeModel.objects, 'bulk_create')
@mock.patch.object(SomeModel, 'save')
def a_dry_run(mocked_bulk_create, mocked_save):

   def print_bulk(obj_list):
       print 'doing bulk_create'
       for obj in obj_list:
          print obj

   def print_save(instance):
       print 'doing save'
       print instance

   mocked_bulk_create.side_effect = print_bulk
   mocked_bulk_create.return_value = True
   mocked_save.side_effect = print_save
   mocked_save.return_value = True
```

The problem is that when I do `bulk_create` instead of `print_bulk` it executes `print_save`. How do I fix that or is there a cleaner way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of argument should be reversed. As you can see at [Quick Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) where describe `patch` the order of mock arguments passed to the function follow `patch`'s decorator from bottom to top.

In you case simply change the patch order or the function signature like

```
def a_dry_run(mocked_save, mocked_bulk_create):
```